# Interpretation of level-log IV estimation where units are shares

Tags: interpretation, logarithm

I have a statistic related question to this equation:

y= b + b1(ln)x + e

where y and x are both shares (given in 0-1)

As I understood the interpretation of level-log function is as follows:

delta(y) = (b1/100) %delta(x)

Given the estimation results for the equation

Ln (x) : -0.53** (0.094) 
--- How would be the interpretation?

From my understanding I would assume the following interpretation:
A 1% increase in x would lead to a decrease of 0.53 percentage points in y (since these are shares they would normally be interpreted as 53, but I think they need to be divided by 100 again due to the given interpretation of the functional form, that's why I come up with 0.53).

I am very confused with the interpretation of level-log involving shares since someone told me that the interpretation should be different.

Does somebody have an idea about this case?

Thank you very much, your help would be highly appreciated!